Certain keys on my PC keyboard don't work sometimes
I have a Meetion K9320 keyboard that used to work fine for around 4 months now but since yesterday a set of keys randomly went dead, they are:

Up arrow
Left arrow
Home
End
Numpad plus
Numpad enter

This deadly combo of dead keys affects my text editing experience.
A strange behavior I noticed when this happens is when pressing Right arrow (functional) + Up arrow + Left Arrow all at the same time it sends a numpad zero keypress???
I am on Windows 10 latest version.
It may be a software problem but I have no Idea what may have caused it.

After something fell on a keyboard, I had a similar issue. On opening it, I found one tiny surface-mount diode loose in the case, and another hanging from the PC board, barely attached. That diode that was just hanging-on pointed out the spot where the other diode came from and I was able to resolder one and replace the loose diode with a IN914 with leads. Hopefully, your repair will be as simple.

@DrMoishePippik No physical damage was applied to the keyboard as far as I know

This is difficult to diagnose, but it sounds like an issue with the actual hardware. Potentially a liquid spillage. If you can't get a new one, then you might want to try opening the keyboard up and cleaning all of the contacts with rubbing alcohol.
However, given what you said about the weird behaviour of the pressure on the board, there could be an issue with the circuit board of the keyboard.
Long story short, sounds like hardware and you might need to purchase a new (or new-used) one.

Despite the Meetion website stating that this keyboard is water proof, I have not spilled any liquid on it.

Ok, so it might not be a liquid spill, but it sounds like something within the keyboard is broken or failing very slowly

It turned out to be a driver problem.
I opened up Windows device manager, selected my keyboard then "Update driver", and choose to select a driver from the default available ones Windows provides, I ended up choosing the generic HID keyboard driver since my keyboard brand wasn't listed, it now works well and all keys are functional.
What's kinda strange though is that I choose the same generic driver that was present when the problem took place.

Well it turns out I'm wrong. after I posted this answer the problem returned, tried repeating the steps but it didn't get fixed this time.
